Using colon to add reason for the statement
As the usage rules of colon states, you can use it to explain something further, like adding details or a list.
Can I use colon to add "reason" by replacing "because" in a sentence?
For ex,

He is a cheat: he lied about the trip

That's just a simple example I can think of. I would like to know if colon can be used this way.

Note that the colon doesn't specifically imply "because", it just implies some close relationship between the two ideas.

Yes, a colon can be used at the end of a complete statement (an independent clause, a fully formed thought) to introduce a summary, a restatement, an elaboration, or an explanation of what was presented in the preceding independent clause.
Examples:
Michael studied hard for one purpose: to pass his examinations.
Though my mother disagrees, I stand by my opinion: we cannot afford to buy a new car.
I know the best way to quench one’s thirst: beer.

Completely unrelated to the question or the answer, but I once saw a tv show that tested which of various beverages was actually best at quenching thirst, and the winner was… milk!

@JanusBahsJacquet - maybe that's for the same reason that it soothes a mouth burned by chillies or hot curry

Perhaps related (I don’t recall the details), but I think the chilli thing is because capsaicin, which is insoluble in regular water, is quite easily soluble in fats like the lipids in milk and yoghurt.
